# Hide and show the div on particular path

Tags: angular

I have div and I need to show it on a particular(mentioned below) path. Thanks in advance.

Path

`{ path: 'preview/:questionid', component: QuestionPreviewComponent, outlet: 'questions' }`

`http://localhost:3000/admin/questions/(questions:preview/5cb18f686560a2f98b43f8e0)`

Routing Module

```js
 imports: [RouterModule.forChild([
    { path: '', redirectTo: 'questions', pathMatch: 'full'},
    { path: 'questions', component: QuestionsComponent, children: [
      { path: '', component: QuestionListComponent, outlet: 'questions' },
      { path: 'bulk-upload', component: BulkUploadQuestionsComponent, outlet: 'questions' },
      { path: 'new', component: NewEditQuestionComponent, outlet: 'questions' },
      { path: 'edit/:id', component: NewEditQuestionComponent, outlet: 'questions' },
      { path: 'preview/:questionid', component: QuestionPreviewComponent, outlet: 'questions' }

    ]}
    ])],
```

I want to achieve this using `*ngIf="router.url == 'path'` but i don't know the way to give my path in that `path`

Comment: How can we guide you? without knowing where your `div` is?

Comment: I just need to know how to use *ngIf  with that route

Comment: what about `<div *ngIf="router.url.indexOf('/admin/questions/')==0">...</div>`? (I suppose you has in constructor `constructor(public router:Router){}` -see that you need use "public"-)

Answer (score 0):

There is couple of ways to do that one of them is as below...

I guess you have CSS code which shows your div
suppose your class name is **.displayDiv** that class only hit when your the URL is something.
 http://localhost:3000/admin/questions/(questions:preview/5cb18f686560a2f98b43f8e0)

on component.ts file of QuestionPreviewComponent where you have to take variable like below...

```
pathName: any;
```

on

```
ngOnInit() {
this.pathName = location.pathname.split('/');
}
```

on HTML file of QuestionPreviewComponent

```
<div [ngClass]='pathName[2] === questions ? "displayDiv" : ""'>
------------------
------------------
Your code
-----------------
-----------------
</div>
```

You can leave else condition or add hide CSS if you prepare

Comment: cant we do in an angular way using *ngIf

Comment: can u show another method.this one seems to be little unusual