# show the div only on particular path

Tags: angular

I have div and I need to show it on a particular(mentioned below) path.Thanks in advance.

Path

`{ path: 'preview/:questionid', component: QuestionPreviewComponent, outlet: 'questions' }`

`http://localhost:3000/admin/questions/(questions:preview/5cb18f686560a2f98b43f8e0)`

Routing Module

```js
    imports: [RouterModule.forChild([
        { path: '', redirectTo: 'questions', pathMatch: 'full'},
        { path: 'questions', component: QuestionsComponent, children: [
          { path: '', component: QuestionListComponent, outlet: 'questions' },
          { path: 'bulk-upload', component: BulkUploadQuestionsComponent, outlet: 'questions' },
          { path: 'new', component: NewEditQuestionComponent, outlet: 'questions' },
          { path: 'edit/:id', component: NewEditQuestionComponent, outlet: 'questions' },
          { path: 'preview/:questionid', component: QuestionPreviewComponent, outlet: 'questions' }

        ]}
        ])],
```

i tried this but it wasn't working.

```js
    <div style="margin-left:3% ;" *ngIf="router.url == 'questions/preview/:questionid'">

    .....code.....

    </div>
```

Comment: Can you include all relevant code. It's not clear where in your component hierarchy the div that you want to hide is.

Comment: that div in  A component but that A component is reused in several components and i want to display div in one particular component and i mentioned the route for it in above question.

Comment: That's still very little information. Could you provide the bare minimum amount of code, and maybe some kind of demo?

Comment: No. i think u got it wrong. I just want to know how to access this path "preview/questionid " using that *ngIf with router.url. because it has dynamic id and i also don't know what more i can provide.

Comment: My view on this is that you are looking at the problem in the wrong way. I think it's bad practice to tie presentation logic to a URL. Instead I would let the components define what should be displayed. You have asked a very specific question that assumes that there is only one way to solve your problem. I think there is a better way to solve your problem, but it requires more information.

Comment: @Prem, Please **DON'T** duplicate questions, in your profile you can see your questions, your same question is on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61767329/hide-and-show-the-div-on-particular-path.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Hide and show the div on particular path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61767329/hide-and-show-the-div-on-particular-path)

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the `questionid` from the `ActivatedRoute` and then use it in your `*ngIf` condition

```
questionid: string;

constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {}

ngOnInit() {
  this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
     this.questionid = params['questionid']; // Save Question Id in a variable
  });
}
```

Use the above variable in your template.

```
<div style="margin-left:3% ;" *ngIf="router.url == ('/admin/questions/preview/' + questionid)">

.....code.....

</div>
```